# How to stop check boxes aligning to their text

Tags: java, css, javafx, checkbox

As you can see in [THIS](https://gyazo.com/3f83c70db36e21c0d19a68627ab3739d) picture: i have 2 check boxes with a text attribute, the issue here is that since the text is not equal and the boxes are centered to the middle the box actually moves to keep it in the middle. Is there any way to make it so that only the text moves and the box stays in a static location like [THIS](https://gyazo.com/23ba41268eb2b156a5e022f5c5d85c20) but without aligning it to anything except the middle.
Snippet of the checkbox in the fxml file:

```
           <JFXCheckBox checkedColor="#8d897d00" focusTraversable="false" graphicTextGap="0.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="690.0" styleClass="runechanger-check-box" stylesheets="@../stylesheet.css" text="No Away" textFill="#8d897d" unCheckedColor="#8d897d00" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
           <font>
              <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
           </font>
        </JFXCheckBox>
```

[THIS](https://pastebin.com/gZyNwiJD) is the full fxml containing the checkboxes

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (including the complete fxml - _here_ not somewhere else). Plus clarify what you are after - the boxes left-aligned and the text centered, like having two columns where the first contains the box and the second the centered text? Instead of screenshots of what you don't want you might provide a scribbled picture of what you want :)

Comment: I literally added a screenshot of what i want and a snippet of the issue and a full reproducable fxml. Maybe read the post?

Answer (score 0):

The alignment is related to the font-size of the label and the height of the checkbox. Both must have the same value. Changing the font-size of form will give both the correct value.

For example in this html

```
<form>
    <div class="check">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> This checkbox is aligned</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

the text and checkbox are vertically aligned with this css

```
form {
    font-size: 16px; /* this value will change font-size and checkbox height */
}
.check {
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* space between form fields */
}
.check label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
}
.check input {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: the question is about javafx, not html :)